# IR laser detection

Tags: laser, detection, sensing

I'm currently trying to characterise a NIR 940nm laser device that I have recently made.  The main thing I want to achieve is to see if the laser is truly doing what the enable signal told it to.

I began with a rather slow square wave - 10Hz at 50% duty cycle. I used a ThorLabs DET08CL photodetector that is pointed directly at the laser, with its output connected to an oscilloscope.

I was expecting some square waves on the scope, instead I got this:

[image: oscilloscope screen capture]

The rising edge seemed all good, yet it doesn't stay high for half the period. Instead it begins to fall, where the falling doesn't look like a normal "1ns fall time" per datasheet. My guess was that the optical feedback coming from the laser, reflected by the photodiode may cause it, but I was unsure.

Please let me know if you think this is a good way of characterising the laser waveform, or if you have better ideas.

- Additional info: I convinced myself that the laser is functional, through a less reliable method: I replaced the photodetector with an IR visualizer card, and further dropped the square wave frequency to 1Hz at 50% duty cycle. I could tell that the visualizer flashes, with each blink approxiamtely 0.5 second, with bare eyes. If what's from the oscilloscope was true, I believe that the blinks on the visualizer would be too fast to be captured by eyes. Hence seeking improvements on the photodiode setup, or alternatives.

Comment: How is your photodetector powered? It looks like these require an external load resistor; do you have your scope set to 50 Ω termination or high-impedance termination?

Comment: How are you coupling the laser to the detector? It looks like this detector is meant to be connected to optical fiber.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @Hearth , the photodetector is powered through a newly replaced battery inside. I was using a high-impedance external termination load resistor, as well as for the scope. Apologize for the mistake for the phototiode part name - should've been the DET08CL - all same except from open-space input rather than optical fiber. I'm inspired by the answer from user1850479 that it might be because the load's too high. Will try lower that and do it again.

Answer (score 1):

The Thorlabs documentation for that part has a very nice tutorial explaining how to use photodiodes:

https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=1295

You should read the whole thing, but I'll quote the relevant bits here.

[image: quote from Thorlabs documentation]

[image: quote from Thorlabs documentation]

If you use the 50 ohm termination they spec, then your bandwidth is 1/(2*pi*50*0.3E-12), or about 10 GHz, and your fall time is 0.35/10GHz = 33 ps.  they spec twice that, probably because your wiring is going to add capacitance.

In your case, you are measuring about a million times slower, so probably you have a large load resistance and have added a lot of capacitance, probably from cabling. Try dropping the load resistance to 50 ohms and see if you get the result you expect.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! @user1850479. Would like to apologize for having the photodetector part No. wrong - should've been the DET08CL - open-sapce input rather than optical fibre, but that doesn't make a huge difference. Thanks for the link to the tutorial, I will read through it. I believe that the load resistor should be one of the reasons for the unexpected result.

Comment: This addresses the long fall time, but from the question it seems there's also a problem with the pulse width: the scope's at 1 ms/div, so the pulse is about 1 ms long, but they claim the input pulse is 50% duty at 10 Hz, which should be 50 ms long.

Comment: That's where I thought optical feedback may come into play - the input side of the photodetector has some reflective metal finishes surrounding, which seems possible for optical feedback to occur and thus causing power drop of the laser at every rising edge.